# Como criar uma coluna em uma tabela a partir de um Select

Tags: mysql

Tenho a tabela *users* e a tabela *posts*, preciso copiar as mesmas informações de uma coluna da tabela users para uma coluna da tabela posts, Por exemplo, eu tenho esse código:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.username
FROM posts
  inner join users on (posts.user_id = users.id )
```

que me trás uma consulta de exatamente o que eu preciso, mas no meu projeto em php preciso que essa coluna seja criada, para conseguir visualiza-la pelo meu html.

Mais um exemplo para ajudar no entendimento da minha pergunta, se eu executar o código:

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD COLUMN user_id INT(11);
```

ele consegue criar exatamente o que eu preciso, mas com o campo *"id"* que esta na tabela users, mas somente com o *"id"*, se eu fizer o mesmo código com o campo que eu preciso, que é o *username*: "user_username", me retorna nulo.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas seu caso parece ser resolvido criando uma [**View**](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/8765/mysql/trabalhando-com-views-no-mysql/)

Comment: Não ficou clara a questão, qual a sua dúvida exatamente ? Popular a tabela com a informação do código do usuário que escreveu o artigo ?
Qual tipo de relacionamento a tabela articles possui com a de posts e de usuários?